# How to add SharePoint App to Site using PnP Powershell script

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

[image]

[image]

I manually do these now. Is there a way to automate the above steps via PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0):

You need site owner permissions to be able to add apps to SharePoint Online Site.

Refer to my PnP Powershell script:

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Legal"
$AppName = "Modern Script Editor web part by Puzzlepart"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online App Catalog site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Get the App from App Catalog
$App = Get-PnPApp -Scope Tenant | Where {$_.Title -eq $AppName}
 
#Install App to the Site
Install-PnPApp -Identity $App.Id
```